# Duplicate Order Increment ID Issue

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, customer

I'm experiencing a rare issue where existing customers completing checkout place the order successfully. However, the following strange behavior occurs:

- The order confirmation email is not sent,
- The order is assigned to the customer correctly, yet customer_id is set to 0, and
- If the customer places the order again, it works correctly (order confirmation email sent and customer ID assigned correctly) **however**, the `increment_id` assigned is precicely the same as the first order and as a result there is a duplicate order increment id, with both orders active.

As I mentioned, the issue is quite rare, we receive over 20 to 30 orders a day, and it only seems to happen once a day, if that.

**Edit**: as per comment, it is useful to note that I am using an extension which allows alphanumeric order increment_ids, [Aschroder Set Custom Order Number](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aschroder-set-custom-order-number.html), our orders follow a trend as follows: OR1000, OR1001, OR1002, OR1003, etc. We have been using this extension for over 10,000 overs without this issue appearing before.

I am also using [ASchroder.com SMTP Pro Email - Free and Easy Magento Emailing for SMTP, Gmail or Google Apps email](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aschroder-com-smtp-pro-email-free-and-easy-magento-emailing-for-smtp-gmail-or-google-apps-email.html) to integrate google mail support for Magento.

**Update 1:** Looking at `exception.log` the following entry is notable which occured around the time of the incidents:

```
 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message 'Unable to connect via TLS' in /html/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php:211
```

It seems like this could cause the order creation process **not** to reserve the order increment id on the quote model.

Is there a way that I can diagnose what is causing this behavior? All other orders placed seem functionally correct.

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party/custom checkout module? Any insight in `/var/log/exception.log` or `/var/log/system.log`? If you have logging enabled or not.  It sounds like Foreign Key restraints. Also what are you using for your session storage in `local.xml`?

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect an extension we're using for increment_ids to be alphanumeric. In terms of local.xml, `<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>`. Regarding the error logs, something noteable which happened around the time of order placement was `exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message 'Unable to connect via TLS' in /html/lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php:211`

Comment: Regarding the exception.log issue with the email, could it be possible that Magento does not complete reserving the order increment id if the email fails to send to the customer?

Comment: Ashley is on here and maybe of help. I sent him a tweet with this issue. https://twitter.com/molotovbliss/status/438618372142415872

Comment: Might not be related to your issue, but watch out with alphanum order IDs. Magento has a bug in `sales/quote` resource model (fixed during the Hackathon): here the increment is cast to `int`, see `isOrderIncrementIdUsed()`. This gave us some headaches in a multistore installation.

Comment: @fmrng: that is strange, did removing the `int` cast resolve the issue in your instance?

Comment: @moose: yes it did, but like I said I'm not sure if this is related to your problem.

Comment: Does SetStartOrderNumber allow alpha-numeric?! Are you sure you're using it? SMTP Pro has detailed logging in system.log have you checked in there (you need to enable logging)?

Comment: @Ashley Schroder: It does indeed, with the order prefix enabled. The values stored in `sales_flat_order` under `increment_id` are alphanumeric. I did post the error message in `system.log` in my first comment, the `Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception` issue. Still not quite sure what caused the issue, it's happened once again since then.