# Same customer places duplicate order

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, quote

I've observed a strange behavior whereby a customer managed to place three orders in quick succession which had the same order numbers.

Each order was based on the same `quote_id` which in turn represents the correct `reserve_order_id` value. The orders were placed at these times:

- 2014-12-15 16:41:11
- 2014-12-15 16:43:10
- 2014-12-15 16:46:39

The first order had the order confirmation email sent to the customer, but the second and third orders did not.

How did each order have the same order number even though the `sales_flat_quote` table seemingly correctly set the value for `reserve_order_id`?

P.S. I've noticed this same issue pop up about 2 - 3 times a month, so very rarely (upwards of 800 orders are placed monthly).

**Edit 1:** As soon as a customer clicks the *Place Order* button during checkout on our website, the button vanishes & the following loading symbol is displayed:

[image]

As such this cannot be as a result of the customer repeatedly hitting the Submit Order button.

Comment: You're assuming no Javascript issues and that the script that hides your Submit Order button works on every platform. I had to setup event tracking on the checkout page to rule out stealthy issues like this before. You can use Google Analytics or create your own form of analytics but I like to know how long my users spend on the site, how many times they clicked certain buttons, if they ever saw the success page, etc. Sometimes advanced logging is the only way to track down UX issues like this. Try this: http://trackjs.com/

Answer (score 5):

I've seen something like this before where a shop was a bit slow on redirecting the customer from the checkout to the Payment portal.

The user clicked the submit button multiple times which caused several orders to be created. So there isn't really a technical issue here, more an user UI issue.

I would advice to first of all call the customer and ask him what happened and maybe display a clear loader or even hide the submit button after the user has clicked it in the checkout

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input, really appreciate it. I also had a sneaking suspicion that this may be the case, but we actually do get rid of the Submit Order button the moment it is clicked. We also do not redirect to a payment portal. This one really has me stomped.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Kirchbergerknorr_DuplicateOrders](https://github.com/kirchbergerknorr/Kirchbergerknorr_DuplicateOrders) module to change status of duplicated orders.

Use this SQL to check how many duplications you have:

```
select 
increment_id, state, email_sent, grand_total, created_at, quote_id as q, 
(select count(x.quote_id) 
from sales_flat_order as x 
where x.quote_id = q 
group by x.quote_id) as count 
from sales_flat_order having count > 1 order by quote_id desc, created_at desc;
```

As you see that problem is that some emails wasn't sent.

Possible reasons can be:

- overloaded sendmail
- blocked sendmail
- closed ports

Related questions:

- [Duplicate Orders](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3963/duplicate-orders)
- [Duplicate Order Increment ID Issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15758/duplicate-order-increment-id-issue)